# Use Gdal from Python IDE

Tags: python, gdal

I am just starting to experiment with writing python scripts. I have been using QGIS and the Osgeo4w shell for sometime now.

I would like to be able to call Gdal from the python IDE i have installed (spyder).

Does anybody have any suggestions in getting this to work? I have QGIS with OSgeo installed and Spyder on windows 7.

Comment: from osgeo import gdal - that's the first step. There is a tutorial (multi-lingual) for GDAL http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html that has some python examples (import gdal doesn't seem to work on the osgeo install).. is there anything in particular that you're having problems with?

Comment: If i try use from osgeo import gdal i get: No module named osgeo

Comment: do you have more than one python install? did you install the correct version for your python? is your GDAL install the same platform (32/64 bit)?